# Strongswan DNS Leak with split-tunnel

Tags: vpn, tunneling, strongswan

I've set up Strongswan VPN with StrongMan(web-interface manager) on AWS.
It works great, my company employees can access contry-restricted site without any issues. But now I need to implement split-tunneling, because we also have to send terabytes of data, daily, to non-restricted sites.

I've coded small C# app that automaticaly manages split-tunneling routes with next command.

```
route ADD siteIP MASK 255.255.255.255 10.10.10.1 IF VPNInterfaceID
```

And it doesn't work like i'd like it to work.
Problem is: my DNS are leaking in split-tunnel mode.

If i route to "www.whatismyip.com" thru VPN, it masks my IP, so it works,
but i can't access restricted sites.

So i routed "www.dnsleaktest.com" thru VPN, and i can see that my DNS are in fact leaking.

I've found an app "Simple DNSCrypt", which fixed my problem, but i really dont want to use third-party software.

I'am very new to this topic, so any help would be appreciated.
I cant figure out how to hide my DNS.
Even overriding to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 doesnt help.
What can i do? What should i read and learn? What could be the problem?

Sorry for my poor use of English.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Maybe, this answer will help someone someday.
You have also route DNS adresses thru VPN (in my case 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4),
and "disabling" default ethernet adapter DNS by setting them to 127.0.0.1.
Dont forget to revert them back after disconnecting from VPN!